# How to enable Facebook Business API for Whatsapp Connection

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I am trying to connect my WhatsApp Business Account with Facebook so that it shows my business name. As per https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2087193751603668?helpref=faq_content there shall be an option for WhatsApp Account in business.facebook.com under 'Business Settings' > Accounts. But it is not there. It also says:

> If the WhatsApp accounts option is not visible, the Business API may
>   not be available to you yet.

So can anyone guide how to get Business API access?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/faq#faq_1807206352701689:

> **How do I get the WhatsApp Business API?**
>   In order to ensure a high quality experience for businesses and users, we're in a limited public preview. If you'd like to work with us, submit more information about your business for consideration as we continue to expand our availability, or reach out to your Facebook representative if you already have one.

If you have such a representative available, reach out to them; otherwise, you will simply have to wait until this becomes available to everyone.